# "This answer is now being edited by [user]" label when a post is being edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

It happens a lot that the same question is being edited by multiple users, causing it to be sometimes overwritten or having almost the same edit by two different users.

I want to suggest having something like:

> "This question is being edited by [user]"

that shows up when someone is editing a post.

It might be very helpful in many cases, for example seeing that senior member is editing a badly formatted question, or user that answered a question is editing it to improve its content. I'm not a designer, but to illustrate my point:

[image: Edit]

There might be many options for this feature, perhaps checkboxes to indicate what's the purpose of the edit, and the action will be appended to the label:

- formation
- content improvement
- code fixes
- adding references

Comment: @GrantWinney I thought about this too. I think a no-activity timer can handle this. I'm only speaking general, much more details should be considered.

Comment: This is an interesting feature that might prevent edit conflict slightly better, but I agree with Grant's arguments. In addition, I'm thinking of a case when a *new* post is edited by many editors at the same time. How would they react when they know about it? Should they stop, or continue editing and submit, or? Without coordination/communication, the message might be more distracting than being useful.

Comment: @AndrewT. One editor shouldn't be shown the message, so they can continue their edit.  Other editors see the message, which should suggest they wait.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom or use Ethernet-style randomized backoff somehow.

Comment: You're assuming that people with a lot of reputation make good edits... that's definitely not true.

Comment: I didn't assume that

Comment: That's an interesting way to have endless bump loop.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/please-add-a-temporary-freeze-on-editing-posts-when-someone-starts-editing

Comment: I would expect to see "This question is also being edited by Person Name".  And a timer saying "you have X seconds left to save your edit or this question will be re-opened to other users"