# Rejecting an edit to question, and manually copying content

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

Without showing the place where this had happened, I'd like to get an insight regarding something that just happened:

I have suggested an edit to a question, and as usual, the box indicating the edit is pending review is there:

> Thanks for your edit!
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it
> is peer reviewed.

While waiting, and while the box still appears, I have noticed the question was updated with all of the content of my edit. Note that the edit was quite comprehensive, so there's no way to mistake this.

I am uncertain whether there's any interest for the asker in ignoring the suggestion, but copying the content manually.

It's worth mentioning this might as well just be a mistake by the user, not understanding how to merge an edit, but I now expect there might be an empty-diff edit suggestion in the edit queue, which will probably get rejected.

Is there any way to deal with such situation?

Comment: There is a feature request that might help dealing with such situations: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited

Comment: @MarounMaroun, This is somewhat relevant, but not quite the case. The question was edited by the asker, and my edit was copied word to word. Thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, flagged. Thanks.