# Why are people allowed to edit a new user post simultaneously?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits

I have recently gained review queue access.  I edited a new user's post. When I pressed 'save' I was informed there were pending edits already.

Key question:
**Is the post checked out to me when I'm reviewing it while in first posts review?**

Otherwise I want to ask why SO is asking me to waste my time editing someone's post and then refusing to accept the edits.

*If there's no checkout system behind the scenes, how do we advocate for one?*
(answered by [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited))

If there's some kind of timer that re-opens it to other reviewers/editors, why isn't this made visible to someone editing?
(Still unanswered - is there one?)

Having some indication that someone else is also mid-edit would be good. I like helping, but wasting my time is infuriating.

Comment: Check my feature-request [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited).

Comment: I think it's safe to say my question was not an 'exact duplicate' but hey. Semantics for pedantics.