# Is there a better way to handle conflicting edits?

Tags: feature-request, edits

I just spent several minutes fixing up an otherwise decent question with struggling English. It was rather aggravating to do that work, click "Save edits", and see

> "Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot
>   be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed."

Basically, I just wasted my time.

There has to be a more editor-friendly way of handling this. Here are some suggestions.

1. It would be nice to have some notification that this was the case before (or while) composing my edit. It seems like SO is great about updating everything else in real-time.
2. Could my edit be automatically queued in case the previous edit doesn't pass or just doesn't fix everything?
3. (Alternate to 2) Could I be notified when the conflicting edit is resolved, so I can apply mine if any part of it still makes sense?

Comment: Might be a bit related, my [FR](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-user-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited).

Comment: Regarding 1) - I do believe you already get a notification text when someone else commits changes to the content while you're editing (with the option to reload the content which nukes your changes). Its only absolutely not shouty enough to notice it if you're focused on editing. Historically I used a browser plugin to cache text area content so I could nab it later to deal with stupid session expiration problems, that might be something to think about in this case too.

Comment: Ah, reading again but without dust in my eyes - this is when someone else wins the race condition for committing an edit for review. No I don't think that is communicated, yet.