# Notify others about post being edited

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, user-interface, error-message

(This question is probably related to users <2k rep only.)

I'm often facing this issue in the edit review queue, but it happens "in the wild" too sometimes.

When you start editing the post, the error "review queue is full" doesn't show up. However, after a few minutes editing I cannot save the result, because "another edit is pending". It is quite understandable: the queue is filled only when a post is saved by somebody. Unfortunately, this abandons efforts of all users editing at the same time, except for the lucky one.

I think this can be solved in another way: in addition to the edit queue, there should be another one. The user is put into this queue, when he/she start editing. When somebody else looks at this question, an icon tells that somebody is already editing this post.

When an editor quits without saving (by closing the tab, for example), we don't record his/her leaving. This can be solved with a simple timeout (after, say, 10 minutes the editor is removed from the queue).

This queue should be non-blocking, because, IMO, it should be up to editors whether they want to edit together with somebody else and apply their changes later.

It is most noticeable in the "[First questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review)" review queue. I almost gave up and skipped edits in such cases, because it was too common that other reviewers interfered and my work was just discarded.

Comment: Similar (dupe?) request: [Is there a better way to handle conflicting edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340850)

Comment: That one is 5 years old and has no answers, so not a dupe. I think it is something that could be resolved in 5 years... [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-user-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited) is a very similar too (and much better than mine), comments, no answers. Is there any way to submit a feature request and get staff response?

Comment: [Duplicates work differently on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277952)

Comment: Augh, sorry. Closing then

Comment: I totally share your concern though; it's frustrating to come up with a feature request only to find out someone suggested it 5 years ago and nothing came of it... especially when the old request had some support behind it. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131) helps give some options in those cases, but it's still annoying.

Comment: Twice at least! In 2014 and 2017...