# Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed

Tags: feature-request, edits

I just tried to edit [How do I make the button have rounded corners while still doing the animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038197/how-do-i-make-the-button-have-rounded-corners-while-still-doing-the-animation)

It opened the screen without a hitch, and allowed me to make the modifications I think the post required (getting rid of the repetition in the body, and putting the code into a runnable snippet). After checking the preview (as I do) and clicking save, I am greeted with the following message;

"Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.".

Ok, fair enough that edits be blocked until the pending edit is dealt with - no one wants to deal with merge conflicts.

My issue is that I **wasn't told this up front**. I just spent time formatting and fixing the question, and now I can't save those changes. That's terrible UX.

Can we get this fixed so that you just can't edit when we're in that state?

*EDIT: It seems that `edit` gets greyed out in this scenario, so I think it must have happened while I was already on the edit page. Maybe we need a realtime notification for this event so I know to stop?*

Comment: *"My issue is that I wasn't told this up front."* Because the other editor hadn't finished his edit yet. You both edited simultaneously, but he saved his draft first.

Comment: I think I requested this at one point and it was rejected for reasons: real-time updating is expensive

Comment: The system is just broken. Now you must be careful about not pressing Approve or Decline when you see `edit(1)`, otherwise the post gets locked for a long time until more people vote. One must always use Improve in order to not the post for further edits.

Comment: Also related: ["This answer is now being edited by user” label when a post is being edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-user-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited?noredirect=1&lq=1)